# PyQt5 crash with QThread

Tags: pyqt5

The following minimal code crashes in the QThread's run for loop. This works when removing the widget object.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Widget(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.setText("hello")
        self.show()

class Worker(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
    def run(self):
        for i in range(1,2):
            label = QLabel()
            label.setText(str(i))
            label.show()
            time.sleep(1)
            label.close()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = Widget()
worker = Worker()
worker.start()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From qt5 documentation:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/thread-basics.html

> GUI Thread and Worker Thread
>
> As mentioned, each program has one thread when it is started. This thread is called the "main thread" (also known as the "GUI thread" in Qt applications). The Qt GUI must run in this thread. All widgets and several related classes, for example QPixmap, don't work in secondary threads. A secondary thread is commonly referred to as a "worker thread" because it is used to offload processing work from the main thread.

You can't create widgets in worker thread.
Apparently time.sleep is causing the segfault. You can use QThread.sleep (self.sleep in a thread) instead.

Cheers!

Comment: No problem. If my answer, solves your problem, please mark it as solved :). Cheers!